# Twitter Api Search for users with parameters other than screen name or ID

Tags: twitter

With the twitter api, can I search for users with parameters like account creation date and other params as shown in [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show) link?

Comment: No. The API is quite clear on this https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/search - you can search within the results once you get them though.

Comment: @TerenceEden which means that I would have to iterate through each user from twitter-not at all feasible. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: No, there is no workaround, sorry.